# how to count number of times all mobile numbers were charged in mongo query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Can anyone help me make the query to count number of times a mobile numbers were charged.

Below is my one document:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5cd010da44ad615a97e3e8ef"),
        "_class" : "com.mongo.docs.OCSMongoLog",
        "jsonObject" : {
                "MobileNumber" : "9711202573",
                "microOperationName" : "Deduct amount from user balance.",
                "moduleName" : "OCS",
                "responseRaw" : "<DirectDebitUnitResp><ConversationID>10129190428111</ConversationID><TransactionID>5602870273</TransactionID><Amount>1</Amount>
                </DirectDebitUnitResp>",
                "operationName" : "Direct Debit",
                "id" : 114,
                "createDate" : "2019-05-06 15:21:18.296",
                "requestRaw" : "DebitBalance [conversationId=1012019875615211751, transactionId=, originatingAddress=9711202573, destinationAddress=9711202573, 
                chargingAddress=9711202573, amount=1]"
        }
}
```

in above document charging condition is regex of `<Amount>1</Amount>` in `responseRaw` field.

I want a query that can give me something like this :

```
{
"MobileNumber" : "9711202573", "successCount" : "5",
"MobileNumber" : "9723894992", "successCount" : "1",
"MobileNumber" : "9710172139", "successCount" : "3",
"MobileNumber" : "9720205393", "successCount" : "2"
}
```

I tried something like this :

```
db.oCSMongoLog.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$jsonObject.MobileNumber", count:{$sum : 1}}},{$match:{'jsonObject.responseRaw':{$regex:'<Amount>1'}}}])
```

but its not giving any output.

Comment: I think the `$match` after the `$group` doesn't make sense. See what the output is after running the `$group` (only the group stage).

Comment: How are you arriving at the field `successCount` in the output?

Comment: I read `$match` denotes the condition like `having` in `sql`.. leave `successCount`.. it should come out like : `{ _id : 97192**90, count : 4}` or whatever the result..

Comment: You can use `$match` for the input document fields, but, before the `$group` stage.

Comment: Oh!! superb its DONE!! thanks for your valuable suggestion

Comment: but why is it so that we have to use `$match` before `$group` as I was following this link : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/ it was using `match` after `group` in one example

Comment: See my earlier comment - my _first comment_. Try that and see what is happening.